# How to fix getting status 500 when search result are not found?

Tags: debugging, backend, nestjs

I've search bar in my Angular FrontEnd design and I'm using NestJS for my backend. When ever I type gibberish on my search bar, I'm getting status 500 error on my network response.

It's not supposed to throw error and I'm trying to figure out why my query is erroring out on just not be able to find a value but don't exactly know where to fix it so, I would be really appreciated if by anychance you can help me by just looking at the code.

I did, try catch and thrownoException like this but now it's treating every errors as not found. I'm just trying to find why it's saying error when every I query and the result is not found and fix it.

```js
        try {
            var finalSqlResults = await finalSql.getManyAndCount();
        } catch (error) {
            const result = { pageIndex: 0,
                pageSize: 0,
                results:[],
                totalCount:0} 
           throw new NotFoundException(result);
        }
```

Comment: Did you tried printing the error variable and checked what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated code snippet that you've shared, seems to be returning a NotFoundException from your Service. Whereas if we are trying to handle errors here, we should instead return the newly created result const.

```
  try {
        var finalSqlResults = await finalSql.getManyAndCount();
    } catch (error) {
        const result = { pageIndex: 0,
            pageSize: 0,
            results:[],
            totalCount:0} 
       return result;
    }
```

Also in the Stackblitz that you shared. The IN query may be getting created as blank "()", which may be leading to throwing the 500 Internal Server Error.

```
 if (tags && tags.length > 0) {
    workspaceQuery = workspaceQuery.andWhere(
      new Brackets(qb => {
        qb.where('wstags.tag IN(:...tags)', { tags }).orWhere(
          'ctags.tag IN(:...tags)',
          { tags }
        );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Praveen, is there possible to just make sql query to not erroring out instead of using try catch?.. I think I'll need to figure out why this query is erroring out on gibberish. SQL will return no results if it can't find something. It shouldnt be erroring out.